# what python function replace functionaly for php operator $$

Tags: php, python, variables

hi in php im able to create variable like this

```
$param = array('product', 'brand');
foreach ($param as $item) {
  $$item = $item;
}
```

so the result will be

```
$product = 'product';
```

how can i achieve this in python?

```
param = ['product', 'brand']
for item in param:
  ??? = item
```

Comment: can be helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230896/given-a-list-of-variable-names-in-python-how-do-i-a-create-a-dictionary-with-the

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You can probably just use a dict to archive whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: @ext: im just asking from curiosity ... because sometimes im using it in php, so i was wonder if its something like that possible also in python ... thats all

Comment: +1 because I don't think you deserve the downvotes you've been getting. I wouldn't know though, since they _didn't leave comments explaining them_.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, sanely. Use a dict instead.

```
items = {}
for item in param:
  items[item] = item
```

Answer (score 1):

```
param = ['product', 'brand']
for item in param:
  globals()[item] = item
```

But it's not a good idea to do so.