# Is there a way to create a dict {var_name:var_value} for given variables?

Tags: python

Can I create a function that returns a dict from its inputs? Like:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> d = vars_to_dict(a,b) # or d = vars_to_dict((a,b))
>>> print d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

It doesn't really have to be a function - I don't believe object name is given to the function. I was just wandering if there is a shorthand for creating dicts from vars. Currently I do a lot of this:

```
dict(data=data,index=index)
```

This way I can choose key names when making a dict, but I don't really need to chose them, as they are the names of the variables.

PS: I've seen this question, but it's not quite the same (I'm starting from vars not var names)

[Given a list of variable names in Python, how do I a create a dictionary with the variable names as keys (to the variables' values)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230896/given-a-list-of-variable-names-in-python-how-do-i-a-create-a-dictionary-with-th)

EDIT: this is one of the blocks that "needs" the var-dict:

```
data = []
index = []
for sent in sentences:
    sent_data = []
    sent_index = []
    for word in sent:
        sent_data.append(word[0])
        sent_index.append((word[1],word[2]))
    data.append(sent_data)
    index.append(sent_index)
```

EDIT2: To clarify a bit: I want to know if there is a way to get the name of a variable into a dictionary or a string. And not by manually inputing it.

Comment: You'd need to get the name of a variable given without entering a string, which I don't think is possible.

Comment: Why would you need this? this looks like a very weird programming pattern.

Comment: It's a bad idea, why not start with a dict in the first place.

Comment: I'm creating a list of words for each sentence - so "data" is a list of lists and I'm doing two-level appending (loop). The same for "index". At the end I want to put them together - to get the standard dict style I've used for a number of applications

Comment: Bad programming pattern.

Comment: @DedekMraz: if you want a dict why don't you build a dict from the start ? And what the use of your `vars_to_dict` function in this context exactly ? Please expose your real problem, not what-you-think-is-the-solution...

Comment: Could you give a sample element ``sent`` of ``sentences``, please ? I don't understand what you are doing with each element ``word`` of a **sent** object. Every **word** object has 3 components at least ?

Comment: @bruno: I'd have to write `results['data'][ndex1].append(word)` and then each outer loop `results['data'].append([])` and also track `index1`. @eyquem: I was just showing what the process is; let's say `word=('Susan',0,5)`

Comment: Your above explanation @bruno is incomprehensible to me. I stll don't see what kind of dict you want to obtain in the end, when **data** object and **index** object have been built. I think like bruno that you are in an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so we need you to be more descriptive please

Answer (score 1):

You can call `globals()`, which will return the dictionary of all global variables:

```
>>>a = 1
>>>b = 'foo'
>>>globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, 'a': 1, 'b': 'foo' '__package__': None}
>>>globals()['a']
1
>>>globals()['b']
'foo'
```

The only thing is: you will have to filter out unneeded variables.

Comment: Well that is what was suggested in the related question (link in my question). But I don't really know how to get the names - i just wanted something like `f(a,b)`, not `f('a','b')`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad programming way.
Start from start of dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for yet another constructive comment/answer (?). I'm asking for an arbitrary set of variables to be packed easily into a dict. If referring to my example, I just put it there to show that I'd have to do a lot of refactoring if I wanted to "start from dict".

Answer (score 0):

One trick is to use _ at the beginning of all private members the you can use something like:

```
import types
_vartypes = [types.BooleanType, types.ComplexType, types.FloatType, types.IntType, types.StringType ] # add as required
_vardict = {}
for _name in dir():
   if not _name.startswith('_') and type(eval(_name)) in _vartypes:
      _vardict[name] = eval(name)
```

Rather than using `dict()` you can use `locals()` and or `globals()` both of which return dictionaries.

In those cases you would use something like:

```
import types
_vartypes = [types.BooleanType, types.ComplexType, types.FloatType, types.IntType, types.StringType ] # add as required
_vardict = {}
for _key, _val in globals().items(): # You could do the same with locals()
   if not _key.startswith('_') and type(_val) in _vartypes:
      _vardict[_key] = _val
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm looking to pack existing variables into dict. And I wanted to do this without `eval`.

Comment: The above _will_ pack the existing variables into a dictionary.

Comment: I know. But I would have to change the names to get them out of `globals`. I don't think anymore that this is possible.

Comment: Why would you need to change the names they are already in there as long as they are not private, (starting with _), and are of one of the types I have selected they are there.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this...

```
def vars_to_dict(a,b):
    dict1= {}
    dict[a]=a,
    dict[b]=b,
    return dict1
```

Comment: This will not work - for a=1, the dict will be {1:1}, not {'a':1}

Answer (score -1):

Same question

I canot find the answer too.

might work but will not work in pandas function.

```
a=1
b=2

{k:globals()[k] for k in ['a','b']}
```

Wait for better answer if you know.

Update!

I got it.

`from sorcery import dict_of`

And it works well in pandas function.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sorcery import dict_of
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

def grn_rate(df):
    f=df[df.sex=='Female'].size.sum()
    a=df.size.sum()
    return pd.Series(dict_of(a,f))

tips.groupby('smoker').apply(grn_rate)
```

You will get this.

```
    a   f
smoker      
Yes 651 231
No  1057    378
```

There is a github page for [sorcery](https://github.com/alexmojaki/sorcery)